# DGrid - Single Selection Mode while using Drag and Drop -> Results in multiple selections

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid, dojo-dnd

I am trying to get a DGrid working using the following properties:

- Drag and Drop
- Single Selection

Unfortionatly, this doesn't work quite as easily as I was hoping.  I am declaring my DGrid like this:

```
this._grid = new (declare([OnDemandGrid, DijitRegistry, Selection, DnDGrid]))({
    store: this.store,
    columns: [
        {label: "ID", field:"id", sortable: false},
        ...
    ],
    touchesToScroll: 2, // Required to enable d&d on mobile
    dndSourceType: "grid-row",
    getObjectDndType: function(item){
        return [item.type ? item.type : this.dndSourceType];
    },
    selectionMode: "single"
}, this.gridDiv);
this._grid.startup();
```

For the most part this works well.  DnD is working.  Selection is *mostly* working.  There is just some strange state on occasion.  These are the cases:

---

**Shift Select**:

If I perform a shift select then I will get multiple items looking as if they are selected.  They will have the following css classes attached to them:

```
.claro .dojoDndItemAnchor, .claro .dojoDndItemSelected { ... }
```

[image]

When listening to the `dgrid-select` event, it reports the selected elements correctly.

Attempting to drag the selected elements also works correctly -> only one of them is moved.

***Edit:*** I have found a solution to the **Shift Select** issue.  [It is posted as answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23255950/251589).  I still haven't been able to figure out the next issue.

---

**Programmatic Deselect**:

If I do the following:

1. Select an item
2. Programmaticlly deselect all: `this._grid.clearSelection();`
3. Programmatically select another item: `this._grid.select(row);`
4. Leaves two items looking selected.

[image]

The two items have different styles.  The incorrect one has:

```
.claro .dojoDndItemAnchor, .claro .dojoDndItemSelected { ... }
```

The correct one has:

```
.dgrid-selected
```

As before, when listening to the `dgrid-select` event, it reports the selected elements correctly.

---

It seems like this is the default dojo DnD moduel that is causing me issues.  Looking at the doc it seems like I need to do something with the selector.  Selector has a property called `singular` but I haven't been able to figure out how/where to set this.

Info on singular: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dnd.html#id2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RE programmatic deselect, I think you've found a legit dgrid bug.  I took a quick look at this and issued a [pull request](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/pull/906).  See if that changeset resolves the issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to prevent **Shift Select** the multiple selection issue by using the `dndParams` field.

Instantiating the grid like this will solve the issue:

```
this._grid = new (declare([OnDemandGrid, DijitRegistry, Selection, DnDGrid]))({
    store: this.store,
    columns: [
        {label: "ID", field:"id", sortable: false},
        ...
    ],
    touchesToScroll: 2, // Required to enable d&d on mobile
    dndSourceType: "grid-row",
    getObjectDndType: function(item){
        return [item.type ? item.type : this.dndSourceType];
    },
    selectionMode: "single",
    dndParams:{singular: true} // ADDED THIS.
}, this.gridDiv);
this._grid.startup();
```

---

Still haven't figured out how to deal with programmatic changes.